# Should we have a "Sandbox for Proposed Questions"?

Tags: discussion

Recently I came upon the [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) of Worldbuilding SE, and it seems like a good idea.

I thought of this also because (as some of you might have noticed) I've played posting some general interest questions with answer at favourable times to get them out in the Hot Network Questions list. I got good success with [one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/what-place-on-earth-is-closest-to-the-sun) and modest success in [other](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16164/would-oceans-regenerate-if-removed). I think such questions can be a good tool to attract more people to the Earth Sciences SE community, and they can be more successful if they are drafted with the help of the community in a sandbox like the one they have in Worldbuilding. Some of these "promotional" Q&A can be community work and posted as community wikis as well.

Of course such sandbox could be useful for any question, not only "promotional" ones.

Comment: AFAIK, the reason why [WorldBuilding.SE] (and [CodeGolf.SE]) have [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) is because [writing a good, on-topic question can be hard on those sites](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056), especially for new users. The Sandbox also compromises the reputation needed for [meta participation to 1 rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) so that all users can use it. Of course, it doesn't mean that this site can't have Sandbox...

Comment: @AndrewT. Fair enough. However, by reading questions posted in Earth Sciences SE I would say that writing a good, on-topic question is hard in this site too.

Comment: Could the sandbox be used to weed out "Please identify this rock/mineral" type questions?